# How to find roots and leaves set in jgrapht DirectedAcyclicGraph

Tags: java, graph, jgrapht

My code:

```
import org.jgrapht.graph.DirectedAcyclicGraph;
// ...
private DirectedAcyclicGraph<String, DefaultEdge> graph = new DirectedAcyclicGraph<>(DefaultEdge.class);
// ...
graph.addVertex("x");
graph.addVertex("y");
// ...
graph.addEdge("x", "y");
```

After constructing the graph, how can I get a set of all the roots (vertices with no incoming edges) and of all leaves (vertices with no outgoing edges)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is working, but doesn't strike me as most efficient.

```
// leaves:
graph.vertexSet().stream()
                .filter(key -> graph.outgoingEdgesOf(key).size() == 0)
                .forEach(key -> doLeavesStuff(key));

// roots:
graph.vertexSet().stream()
                .filter(key -> graph.incomingEdgesOf(key).size() == 0)
                .forEach(key -> doRootsStuff(key));
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be:

```
// leaves:
graph.vertexSet().stream().filter(
    key -> graph.incomingEdgesOf(key).size() == 0
).forEach(
    key -> doLeavesStuff(key)
);

// roots:
graph.vertexSet().stream().filter(
    key -> graph.outgoingEdgesOf(key).size() == 0
).forEach(
    key -> doRootsStuff(key)
);
```

intead?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: yes, you're right, I was storing the keys in an additional map and therefore used `keySet`. will edit my answer. next time you can just leave a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
class DAG extends jgrapht.graph.DirectedAcyclicGraph <Node,Edge> {

   Collection <Node> nodes = collected_for_additional_purposes ();

   private int countRoots () {
      int count = 0;
      for (final Node node : nodes) {
         if (inDegreeOf (node) == 0) {
            count++;
         }
      }
      return count;
   }
}
```

It's akin to stream used in accepted answer and one could use an iterator too, but the difference here is using `inDegreeOf (aVertex)`.  Similarly `outDegreeOf` would work too.

As an aside, I tried doing the following, but `count++` generated compiler error "Local variable count defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final".  I'm wondering what a clean, expressive inline syntax might look like.

```
private int countRoots () {
   int count = 0;
   nodes.forEach (node -> {
      if (inDegreeOf (node) == 0) {
         count++;
      }
   });
   return count;
}
```

https://jgrapht.org/javadoc-1.0.0/org/jgrapht/graph/AbstractBaseGraph.html#inDegreeOf-V-

Comment: You can use an `AtomicInteger` to count in the callback

Comment: @Mugen, very good! Works. Thanks.